# What does CMS mean in relation to Java's Garbage Collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

A lot of [JVM's command line arguments dealing with the garbage collector](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html#icms.available_options) have "CMS" prepended to them. What does this stand for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Concurrent Mark Sweep](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/cms-6.html)

(Or as Tom mentions in the comments, *mostly* Concurrent Mark Sweep.)

Comment: Or "(mostly) Concurrent Mark Sweep".

Answer (score 8):

It's a method or algorithm for garbage collection that, in theory, affects the performance of the application less than the older methods.

> The concurrent mark sweep collector,
>   also known as the concurrent collector
>   or CMS, is targeted at applications
>   that are sensitive to garbage
>   collection pauses. It performs most
>   garbage collection activity
>   concurrently, i.e., while the
>   application threads are running, to
>   keep garbage collection-induced pauses
>   short

[G1](http://tech.puredanger.com/2008/05/09/javaone-g1-garbage-collector) is the next level being considered/developed.

Answer (score 1):

See [Memory Management in the Java Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/memorymanagement-whitepaper-1-150020.pdf) for more details....